# How do I pause shareReplay when there are no subscribers

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

For example:

```js
const s = rxjs.interval(2000).pipe(tap(console.log), shareReplay(1))
const b = s.subscribe(v => {})
// wait, console will begin output 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
b.unsubscribe()
// console will continue output 4, 5, 6, 7, ...
```

I want my stream paused when there are no subscribers to save CPU usage.

How do I pause the stream when there are no subscribers ?

The goal is to let multiple subscribers share a single stream.

- When the first subscriber comes, the stream will start with an initial value and provide data periodically.
- When a new subscriber comes, it will get the most recently value in the stream.
- When all subscriber gone, the data stream can be closed safely, next one comes will be treated as first one.

Comment: What RxJS version you have? It looks like `refCount` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a `multicast` to share your data via `ReplaySubject`, with `refCount` to keep track of subscribers count.

```js
const s = rxjs.interval(2000).pipe(
  tap(console.log), 
  multicast(() => new ReplaySubject(1)),
  refCount()
);

const b = s.subscribe(v => {})

setTimeout(()=>{
  b.unsubscribe()
}, 5000)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. But if new subscribers are handled by `refCount`, how can `ReplaySubject` responds immediately when a new subscriber comes.

Comment: @ZangMingJie, as you said, a `ReplaySubject(1)` will push its latest `1` value to all subscribers. And `refCount` is responsible for sharing the same `ReplaySubject` for each "subscription session". Simply saying, it will reset to a new `ReplaySubject` each time all subscribers unsubscribe.

Comment: You can read more about multicasting from RxJS core member articles: https://medium.com/@cartant

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk, if you're willing to promote something -- it at least should cover particular issue. Linking "medium/cartant" is pretty much the same as linking "github/rxjs". First of all we should care about giving answers, promotion should be secondary.